# Python regex negative lookahead - only include result text, not whole text

Tags: python, regex

```
r = r'(?!.*66)get.*on'
txt = "get your kicks on Route 66"
res = re.search(r, txt)
```

I only want res=None if the exclusion text "66" would be included in the result text i.e. between "get" and "on". In this case it's outside the resulting text so I want to see a result but instead it's checking if "66" is anywhere in the whole text and returns res=None. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You call that "lookahead"? I think what's in your code should be called "lookbehind"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a string between two strings excluding a third string, you can use a [*tempered greedy token*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) (see [more details about this construct at rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)):

```
r = r'get(?:(?!66).)*on'
txt = "get your kicks on Route 66"
res = re.search(r, txt)
```

Here, `(?:(?!66).)*` matches any char (other than a line break char if `re.DOTALL` is not specified), 0 or more repetitions/consecutive occurrences, that does not start a `66` char sequence.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dcVfs9/1).

Note that you might want to tune it to get the shortest substring using `r'get(?:(?!get|66).)*?on'` expression.

See an [**updated regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dcVfs9/2).

Comment: If anyone knows a better approach, please post as an answer, and please let me know why this answer is not helpful.